# Leaflet.js: Linking Activities to Map Markers

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js to display markers on the map using latlng coordinates pulled in from the database using php.

I have a list of activities on the left sidebar to which I would like to link these with the map markers together.

I am having difficulty with this:
If you were to hover/click on an activity on the sidebar, the correct marker would then do something, such as the popup or a nice animation.

http://meteaydin.co.uk/tourism/itinerary.php

Here is a link where you can see what I have.

If you could lend me a hand to possibly achieving this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: The link is long dead. The OP hasn't logged in for 2 years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave references to your markers in your links and visa versa. Check the following example:

Create a marker and a link:

```
var marker = new L.Marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('My popup').addTo(map);
    link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'my-link', document.body);

link.href = '#';
link.textContent = 'My link';
```

Create references to each other:

```
link.marker = marker;
marker.link = link;
```

Then add events to your link and use the marker reference in the handlers:

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(link, 'mouseover', function () {
    this.marker.openPopup();
});

L.DomEvent.addListener(link, 'mouseout', function () {
    this.marker.closePopup();
});
```

And it also works the otherway around, attach handlers to the marker and use the referenced link to do something:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function () {
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.link, 'hover');
});

marker.on('mouseout', function () {
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.link, 'hover');
});
```

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gInjWxd84RhPsbIIW4ct?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, ok that works, thanks. However, how would I get this to work across multiple links, which are dynamically generated using php?

Comment: This is how i'm outputting the markers.

marker = new L.marker(<?php echo "[",$data[$x]['latitude'],",",$data[$x]['longitude'],"]"; ?>

Comment: Generate the links and markers on the clientside. Otherwise it will get rather messy. Use XHR to fetch the marker data from the serverside and process it using JS on the clientside. Keeps things nice and tidy. I've added an example to my answer.